# Audio file won't play after uploading Ionic 3 Angular5

Tags: php, angular, ionic3

Hello i want to upload an audio file(.mp3). The file is uploaded on the folder, the value is inserted on the db (MySql) so far so good. But when i try to play the file on the uploads folder is says its corrupted or extension is wrong.the value is not base64 is the original name of the file as shown in the photo here.

[image]

html

```
               <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                  <input type="file" name="avatar" (change)="onFileSelect($event)" />
                  <button type="submit">Upload</button>
                </form>
```

ts

```
  onSubmit() {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('avatar', this.form.get('avatar').value);

    this.group_id = 0;
    this.media.tags = this.hashes;
    this.media.audio = formData;
    this.media.browser = true;
    this.userData.uploadAudio(this.media, this.group_id ).subscribe(
      (res) => {
        this.uploadResponse = res;
          console.log(res);
      },
      (err) => {  
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

php

```
    $mediaData = $request->post('media');
    $name = $mediaData['audio'];
    $uri =  substr($name,strpos($name,",")+1);
    $encodedData = str_replace(' ','+',$uri);
    try 
    {
        $name = md5(time() . rand(1, 1000));
        if(!file_put_contents('uploads/' . $name.'.mp3', $decodedData)) 
        {
        }
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
    }
    $name = $name . '.mp3' ;
```

Comment: can you verify on server that uploaded file exist ?

Comment: Yes it does Ronan. With a different name as the function dictates but it does. Does it have to do with the size of it or the extension? i think if it was an image it will uploaded fine

Comment: If it helps anyone the bytes on the uploaded file is 0 so....